# How to show sum of two elements is decomposable.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, multilinear-algebra, exterior-algebra

Let $V$ be a vector space over the field $F.$ Let $\{v_1,\ldots,v_4\}$ be linearly dependent set. Then how do I show that $w=v_1 \wedge v_2 + v_3 \wedge v_4$ is decomposable ?

Note that to show $w$ is decomposable we have to show that $w=x \wedge y$ for some $x,y \in V.$ What I tried: Atleast one of the $v_i$ can be written as linear combination of the others, so wlog let $v_1=c_2v_3 + c_3 v_3 + c_4 v_4$ then $w= v_3\wedge (c_3v_2+v_4)+v_4\wedge c_4 v_2.$ I think I need some other trick. Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By your work, we have 
$$
w = c_3 v_2 \wedge v_3 + c_2 v_4 \wedge v_2 + 1 \ v_3 \wedge v_4
$$
Now, it suffices to find two vectors $u_1,u_2 \in \Bbb F^3$ whose "cross-product" is
$$
u_1 \times u_2  = (c_3,c_2,1)
$$
for instance, we can take $u_1 = (1,0,-c_3)$ and $u_2 = (0,1,-c_2).$  With that in mind, try computing
$$
(v_4 - c_3 v_2) \wedge (v_3 - c_2 v_2)
$$